# How do I make Dask Dashboard working properly?

Tags: dask

I used AWS EC2 to run everything, in one Jupiter notebook process, I do:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(scheduler_port=5272, dashboard_address=5273,memory_limit='4GB')
# client = Client(cluster)
```

to start a client specifying a port. Then in another process, I join it with,

`client = Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:5272')` 
To check the dash board, I open with safari

`http://ec2-1-123-12-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5273/status`

I could see the dash board, but when i run some big processing tasks, there is no action in the dashboard. still showing little cpu usage. But I saw, huge cpu usage in `htop` , with my `ddf.compute()` running... Did I miss anything?

Comment: Try a simple task, e.g. `client.submit(sum, [1,2,3])`. It might be that the scheduler is busy constructing a very complex graph, so nothing is shown in the dashboard...

Comment: ok... when running this task, there is indeed some blue bar appear out there.... not as fancy as others' dash board...

Comment: Yes, it's a tiny task, so it will not look fancy... the good news is that it works, so the focus should be on figuring out why the submitted task DAG is complex.

Comment: Thanks! I actually retry with a more complex case.... a bit fancier dashboard result indeed shows up. I think the problem is solved now! Thanks so much!